# Call ruby method with 2 params that are changed in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I want to send an API Request using the gem searchbing and defined the following method in my Model. I succeed to get search results but do not know how to change my offset in the view using pagination links.

Model **Search.rb**

```
def self.bing_results_web(search_term_web, offset = 0)
  bing_results = bing_web.search(search_term_web, offset)
end
```

Controller **searchs_controller.rb**

```
def search_m4o
    if params[:search_web, :offset]
        @search_web = Search.bing_results_web(params[:search_web, :offset])
    end
end
```

View

```
<%= text_field_tag :search_web, 
            params[:search_web], 
            placeholder: "#Web Search",
            autofocus: true,
            class: 'form-control search-box input-lg' %>
```

The textfield works fine giving search results (as long as I do not add :offset to the params).So I do not know how to put my Params[:offset] properly starting with 0 and then adding 10 or 50 every time I click on a pagination link.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Method `Search.bing_results_web` accepts **two parameters**, and `params` is **a hash**:

```
def search_m4o
  if params[:search_web]
    @search_web = Search.bing_results_web(
      params[:search_web], params[:offset] || 0
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped for declaring my offset params in the controller. That leaves the question how to change that now in the view? I put this in the view but nothing happened. <% params[:offset] = 10 %>. How to set this params[:offset] to 10 in the view now?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the intent “to set this params[:offset] to 10 in the view,” but you probably need to declare another `text_field` for it, or like.

Comment: bing is only giving 50 search results maximum. To call for the next 50 results you have to change the offset to lets say 51. Then the results 51 till 100 are shown. <%= text_field_tag :offset, params[:offset] || 10 %> I put this now. And it worked :) Thank you so much ...